# What does Namespace mean?

Tags: python

```
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='PROG')
>>> parser.add_argument('-f', '--foo')
>>> parser.add_argument('bar')
>>> parser.parse_args(['BAR'])
Namespace(bar='BAR', foo=None)
>>> parser.parse_args(['BAR', '--foo', 'FOO'])
Namespace(bar='BAR', foo='FOO')
>>> parser.parse_args(['--foo', 'FOO'])
usage: PROG [-h] [-f FOO] bar
PROG: error: too few arguments
```

Is `Namespace` some keyword in Python?

Is it also used in other cases?

Thanks.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Namespace

Comment: @Syn: Here `Namespace` is capitalized in the first letter. I assume it is different from `namespace`,and is a keyword?

Comment: No it's not a keyword, it's the name of a class

Comment: @SyntacticFructose you should consider deleting your comment, its a bit rude but also plainly incorrect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's referring to the [`argparse.Namespace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.Namespace) class. There's nothing special about it; it's not a keyword or anything.